# RSpec - script to upgrade from 'should' to 'expect' syntax?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have hundreds of files that also have hundreds of 'should' statements.

Is there any sort of automated way to update these files to the new syntax?

I'd like options to both create new files and also modify the existing files inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sed is a good tool for this.

The following will process all the files in the current directory and write them out to new files in a `_spec_seded` directory.  This currently handle about 99%+ of the changes but might still leave you with a couple of manual changes to make (the amount will depend on your code and coding style).

As always with a sed script you should check the results, run diffs and look at the files manually.  Ideally you are using git which helps make the diffs even easier.

```
filenum=1
find . -type f -name '*_spec.rb' | while read file; do
  mkdir -p ../_spec_seded/"${file%/*}"
  echo "next file...$filenum...$file"
  let filenum+=1
  cp "$file" ../_spec_seded/"$file"

  sed -i '                           # Exclude:
/^ *describe .*do/! {                # -describe...do descriptions
  /^ *it .*do/! {                    # -it...do descriptions
    /^[[:blank:]]*\#/! {             # -comments
      /^ *def .*\.should.*/! {       # -inline methods
        /\.should/ {
          s/\.should/)\.to/                      # Change .should to .to
          s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/                    # Add expect( at start of line.
          /\.to\( \|_not \)>\=/ s/>\=/be >\=/    # Change operators for
          /\.to\( \|_not \)>[^=]/ s/>/be >/      # >, >=, <, <= and !=
          /\.to\( \|_not \)<\=/ s/<\=/be <\=/
          /\.to\( \|_not \)<[^=]/ s/</be </
          /\.to\( \|_not \)\!\=/ s/\!\=/be \!\=/
        }

        /\.to +==\( +\|$\)/ s/==/eq/
        /=\~/ {                                      # Change match operator
          s/=\~/match(/
          s/$/ )/
          s/\[ )$/\[/
        }

        s/[^}.to|end.to]\.to /).to /                 # Add paren
        /eq ({.*} )/ s/ ({/ ( {/                     # Add space
        /to\(_\|_not_\)receive/ s/_receive/ receive/ # receive
        /\.to eq \[.*\]/ {
          s/ eq \[/ match_array([/
          s/\]$/\])/
        }

        /expect.*(.*lambda.*{.*})/ {                 # Remove unneeded lambdas
          s/( *lambda *{/{/
          s/ })\.to / }\.to /
        }

        /expect *{ *.*(.*) *})\.to/ {                  # Fix extra end paren
          s/})\.to/}\.to/
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' ../_spec_seded/"$file"
done
```

Please use with caution.  Currently the script create new files in `_seded/` for review first for safety.  The script is placed in `/spec` directory and run from there.
If you have hundreds of files this could save you hours or days of work!
If you use this I recommend that "step 2" is do manually copy files from `_spec_seded` to `spec` itself and run them.  I recommend that you don't just rename the whole directories.  For one thing, files, such as `spec_helper.rb` aren't currently copied to `_spec_seded`.

11/18/2013 Note: I continue to upgrade this script.  Covering more edge cases and also making matches more specific and also excluding more edge cases, e.g. comment lines.

P.S. The differences which should be reviewed can be seen with (from the project directory root):

```
diff -r /spec /_spec_seded
```

git also has nice diff options but I like to look before adding files to git at all.

Answer (score 5):

Belated update, mainly for those who may find their way to this page via a search engine.

Use Yuji Nakayama's excellent [Transpec](http://yujinakayama.me/transpec/) gem for this purpose. I've used it over 10 times now on different projects without issue.

From the website:

> Transpec lets you upgrade your RSpec 2 specs to RSpec 3 in no time. It supports conversions for almost all of the RSpec 3 changes, and it’s recommended by the RSpec team.
>
> Also, you can use it on your RSpec 2 project even if you’re not going to upgrade it to RSpec 3 for now.

Comment: This 'should' be the accepted answer.  The transpec gem is considerably better than whipping up your own sed script and handles more edge cases and more rspec 2->3 syntax changes than just should to expect

Comment: @lamont you are a bit old-fashioned :) 
expect(this).to be(the_accepted_answer)